# JUnit Testing Android NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

My project is using a Firebase Realtime Database as its DB storage. I am using MVC architecture with a repository and service layer. I'm trying to unit test a method in the service layer that adds a new user to the database repository.

I'm getting a null pointer exception on the line below and I don't know why. Any ideas?

```
User testUser = svc.SaveUserProfile(u);
```

Here is my unit test code:

```
public class RegistrationActivityTest {

UserService svc;

@Test
public void testAddUserToDb_WhenNone_ShouldSetAllProperties(){
    //act
    User u = new User("1", "John", "john@email.com", "Teacher");
    User testUser = svc.SaveUserProfile(u);

    //assert - that testUser is not null
    assertNotNull(testUser);

    //now assert that the user properties were set correctly
    assertEquals("1", testUser.getUserId());
    assertEquals("John", testUser.getName());
    assertEquals("john@email.com", testUser.getEmail());
    assertEquals("Teacher", testUser.getAccount());
}
```

Here is my service layer and interface code:

```
public class UserService implements IUserService {

//instance of DbContext for firebase handling
private DbContext dbContext;

public UserService(Context context){
    super();
    dbContext = new DbContext(context);
}

@Override
public User SaveUserProfile(User u) {
    User user = new User();
    user.setUserId(u.getUserId());
    user.setName(u.getName());
    user.setEmail(u.getEmail());
    user.setAccount(u.getAccount());

    dbContext.AddUserAccount(user);

    return user;
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IUserService {

User SaveUserProfile(User u);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `svc` is object not created. Create it before using:

`UserService svc = new UserService(context)`

Comment: I changed it to use the UserService interface (IUserService) and created it as you said and it passed, thanks!